# Indoors firearms permanent hearing damage

Tags: self-defense, firearms

What permanent hearing loss results from shooting indoors (2-3 shots)? Pistol, revolver, SMG, carabine, hunting rifle? No ear protection.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it barely relates to martial arts

Comment: This really more of a general health question than anything. There are also extensive writeups available on the types of hearing damage (extensive) that can result from the noise that firearms make.

Comment: Eh, I'd see this as befitting training injuries...

Comment: @JohnP earplugs? Really? In a self-defence situation?! Martial arts are not only about painting and singing.

Comment: @Vorac: Eyeh, like I said, I see this one as a bit borderline, since guns are often not considered in martial arts other than disarms and the like, but I acknowledge that they do fit within the continuum. That said, it is a bit more of a remote case, and the question was posed devoid of extra details that explicitly tie it to martial arts. FWIW, the answer seems very variable.

Comment: @Vorac - No need to be rude. There is nothing in your post about martial arts or self defense, just how much damage from indoor shooting. In addition, I said nothing about ear plugs. I just stated that there were extensive writeups on the damage that can occur, and as it's written, it's a general health type question.

Comment: @JohnP my apologies on being rude. Furthermore thanks to everyone about the comments (actually mini-answers). This is a general health question. It should be asked to such an audience.

Comment: @Vorac - No worries. Unfortunately, general health questions are not that welcome on any site on the network. What you could do is rephrase it asking if there have been any studies showing the effects of gunfire on hearing without protection on the medical sciences stack. Something like "I have heard that even a single shot can produce x,y,z effects, have there been any studies done on a, b and c" kind of thing.